# If $a^4 = 1$ and $ab = ba^2$ in a group, show that $a = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $a^4 = 1$ and $ab = ba^2$ in a group, show that $a = 1$. I haven't been able to make much progress with this question. Is there some trick that am I missing?

Comment: Does the second equation hold $\forall b\in G$ or just for a special $b\in G$? If it holds $\forall b\in G$ (e.g. $b=1$), then $a^4=1$ is superfluous.

Comment: I would assume just a special b which may or may not = e.  If you can get a=ab for *any* b you are golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try multiplying on the left by $a.$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just got now that $a^2 = 1$ when I saw your edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply on the right by $a^2$, simplify the LHS. This should give you a value for $a^2$; substituting into the original equation should give you the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show $ax = x$ or alternatively $a^4x =x = a^3x$.

Well how about $b$.  Does $b = a^3b$?

Let's see:  $a^3b = a^2 ba^2 = aba^4 = ab = ba^2$. Darn!  It didn't work. But we did get. $a^3b = ab$ so  $a^3b = a^2(ab) = ab \implies a^2 = e$.

So $ab = ba^2 = b$.  Therefore $a = e$.

Answer (score 1):

multiply on the right by $b^{-1}$
$$
a=ba^2b^{-1}\tag{1}
$$
Square to get
$$
a^2=ba^4b^{-1}=1\tag{2}
$$
Plug $(2)$ into $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
&a^4=1
\implies 
ba^4=b
\iff ba^2a^2=b
\iff aba^2=b \\
\iff & a(ab)=b
\iff a^2b=b
\iff a^2=1
\end{align}

then we have the condition $a b = b a^2$, so it becomes $ab=b$
i.e, $a=1$.